# Angular $http post request undefined in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

Not able to make `$http` post request, getting undefined for `$_POST["name"]` in php and for all other posted data. but in my console printing all the data correctly, can u help me where I did mistake. I am sending data when click event is triggered, I am new to angular, please help me to solve this problem, Thanks to replies in advance.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#applyJob')).unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    console.log($scope.userName+$scope.userEmail+$scope.userMobileNo+$scope.subject+$scope.userCoverLetter+$scope.attach);
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "mailer.php",
        data: {
            name : $scope.userName,
            mail : $scope.userEmail,
            no : $scope.userMobileNo,
            subject : $scope.subject,
            message : $scope.userCoverLetter,
            attach : $scope.attach
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    });
});
```

my `php` code looks like below

```
require ('smtp_lib/phpmailer.php');
require ('smtp_lib/smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yyyyyy";
$mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->AddAddress("zzz@gmail.com");
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["mail"]);
$mail->Body = $_POST["message"].'<br>'.$_POST["no"];
$mail->AddAttachment($_POST["attach"]);
$mail->Send();
```

if I open `php_error_log` I getting these errors

```
[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 16

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: subject in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 17

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 20

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 21

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 21

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 21

[29-Apr-2015 08:44:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: no in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\contact-form\files\contact_mailer.php on line 21
```

Comment: your code seems to be right, can you `var_dump($_POST)` and share the result

Comment: There is no clue in it. Can you check in your console if ajax request is sent to server and if yes, it is send as a form post like this in example
http://blog.yiiframe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/form-post-angularjs.jpg

Comment: Did you test your web service in postman or any other rest client. If you did post response in it your question.

Comment: @yiiframe i getting success, if success means the data is sent to server right

Comment: Remove the extra header and try `$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); var_dump($post);`

Comment: did you check what is passed in POST of ajax request in console

Comment: Can you paste  PHP code also?

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar i pasted my php code also

Comment: @yiiframe can u help to check passed POST of ajax request in console, i googled but cant able to get solution.

Comment: @Selva, its simple, 1)open your console 2) click on #applyJob button
3) you will see an ajax request in console as you click 4) click on ajax request, it will show you all details as I shared with you in image

Comment: @yiiframe in developer mode chrome->networks->mailer.php->Request Payload->I can see the defined data, there.

Comment: @Selva can you check my answer, I hope that gonna work for you.

Comment: @yiiframe I tried your code getting error that `Uncaught ReferenceError: setAsFormPost is not defined`

Comment: thanks to all I found solution to this problem, please find below for the answers.

Comment: you need to pass `setAsFormPost` to your controller, updated my answer for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

I added this above single line in `mailer.php`, my problem solved. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue Angular with Php you can solve this with;

```
var form = {name:"x",mail:"x",no:0,subject:"x",message:"x",attach:"x"};
var formData = new form(); 
formData.name = $scope.userName,
formData.mail = $scope.userEmail,
formData.no = $scope.userMobileNo,
formData.subject = $scope.subject,
formData.message = $scope.userCoverLetter,
formData.attach = $scope.attach

$http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "mailer.php",
        data: formData
});
```

In your php you take this with `file_get_contents("php://input")` ;

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$formData = json_decode($postdata);
echo $formData->name;
```

Comment: I will not say its an issue, its just default `content-type` set in `angular` is `application/json`. you can change them according to your needs and choice

Comment: @hurricane I run your code getting error like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @Selva Actually you need to define a empty object for set elements. You can use formData = new Object(); or create a object.

Answer (score 0):

First check `$scope.userName` if it's defined in the console before send the request and you can write it like this:

```
var data = {
            name : $scope.userName,
            mail : $scope.userEmail,
            no : $scope.userMobileNo,
            subject : $scope.subject,
            message : $scope.userCoverLetter,
            attach : $scope.attach  
          }

$http.post('mailer.php', { params: data }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // something
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // something else
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a directive to set as form post for all your http post request. your php code will remain the same

```
//Directive - change App with your app name
    App.factory("setAsFormPost", ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
            var headers = getHeaders();
            headers[ "Content-type" ] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            return($.param(data));
        }
        return(transformRequest);
    }]);

// you need to pass setAsFormPost to your controller like this
        App.controller('ControllerName',
        ['$scope','setAsFormPost', '$http', function($rootScope, $scope, messageHandler, settings, yiiBox, yiiHttp) {
        $http.post('mailer.php', {name : $scope.userName, mail : $scope.userEmail,
                no : $scope.userMobileNo, subject : $scope.subject, message : $scope.userCoverLetter,
                attach : $scope.attach}, {transformRequest: setAsFormPost}).success(function (result) {
            //something
        }).error(function (error) {
            //something
        });
    }]);
```